# Appcelerator REST Complex Custom Object Update

Tags: angularjs, rest, appcelerator-acs

All,

TL:DR

- Appcelerator Cloud Services
- REST
- Custom Object with arrays
- Update property in an array using $inc atomic increment operator

Details:

I am using AngularJS to access Appcelerator Cloud Services using REST. I have a complex custom object (see Gist links below). My custom collection will contain one of these objects per event. Each event has teams, and each team has contestants. Each team and contestant competes in event segments, and the audience votes on team and contestant performance. I want to update team and contestant scores, but I can't figure out how I need to set the fields value in order to update scores.

I've created a gist with all my files that are involved in this issue. If anyone could please provide some assistance I'd appreciate it.

- [ScoreObject](https://gist.github.com/bp4151/62a90d815d0c738a621e#file-scoreobject)
- [ScoreService](https://gist.github.com/bp4151/62a90d815d0c738a621e#file-scoreservice-js)
- [VoteController](https://gist.github.com/bp4151/62a90d815d0c738a621e#file-votectrl-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and changed the score object to a flat document. I now have a score document per event/team/segment or event/contestant/segment. This should allow the score property to be updated easily since there are now no hashes or arrays in the score document.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amhvLu5f/1/)

Let the whole array you have be called 'arr';

```
var arr= {....};
```

Let's deal with the segments, located 3rd key from the top. Then in your HTML, it would look something like this:

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="segment in arr[0].segments">
            <td ng-bind="segment.name"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" ng-model="segment.name">
            </td>
            <td ng-bind="segment.score"></td>
            <td style='cursor:pointer;' ng-click="segment.score = segment.score+1">Add Score</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

And your controller would be something like:

```
var TodoCtrl = function ($scope) {
    $scope.arr = arr;
}
```

It's just an array of objects so think of it like an array of string or a number but with properties. For example, if you want to output all the contestants in the second array, you'd be doing something like

```
arr[1].contestants.forEach(function(element, index, object){
    console.log(element.id, element.name); // name would start with Gene Collier
    element.segments.forEach(function(_el){
            console.log('name', _el.name, 'score', _el.score);
    });
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have the interface portion down, and have the data coming back in my controller. I have been able to isolate the data I need. I just can't get it in the right format to successfully update the score in Appcelerator Cloud Services. All of the examples I have found show how to take a top level score property and increment it. I can't seem to figure out how to take a nested property and increment it.

Comment: Just like how I used ng-repeat in HTML, you can also nest ng-repeat and for each value they can be modified through HTML. something like <tr ng-repeat="c in arr[1].contestants"><td><div ng-repeat="seg in c">{{c.name}}</div></td></tr>